# Menu and submenu generation issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a small project, where the menus and it's sub menus were generated from services. The sub menus are loading for the first time when a main menu is clicked, but the next time, it doesn't load.

**app.component.html:**

```
<li class="treeview" *ngFor="let menu of menus">
     <a href="#" *ngIf="menu.ParentMenuId === 0">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>{{menu.Menu}}</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
           <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
     </a>
     <ul class="treeview-menu" *ngFor="let submenu of menus">
         <li *ngIf="submenu.ParentMenuId === menu.Id"><a routerLink="{{submenu.htmlId}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> {{submenu.Menu}}</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { MenuService } from './services/menu.service';
...
export class AppComponent {
  menus: any;
  constructor(_menuService: MenuService) {
    _menuService.getMenu().subscribe(menus => this.menus = menus);
    console.log(this.menus);
  }
}
```

**menu.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Global } from '../app.globals';

@Injectable()
export class MenuService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  _data: any;

  getMenu() {
    return this.http
      .get(Global.BASE_API_URL+'/api/menus/get/all')
      .map(x => x.json())
  }
}
```

and the json is

```
[
  {
    "Menu": "Master",
    "ParentMenuId": 0,
    "htmlId": "master",
    "Id": 1,
    "Code": null,
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": 0,
    "EnteredDate": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDate": null
  },
  {
    "Menu": "Entity",
    "ParentMenuId": 1,
    "htmlId": "entity",
    "Id": 2,
    "Code": null,
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": 0,
    "EnteredDate": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDate": null
  },
  {
    "Menu": "Entries",
    "ParentMenuId": 0,
    "htmlId": "entries",
    "Id": 3,
    "Code": null,
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": 0,
    "EnteredDate": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDate": null
  },
  {
    "Menu": "Register",
    "ParentMenuId": 3,
    "htmlId": "register",
    "Id": 4,
    "Code": null,
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": 0,
    "EnteredDate": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDate": null
  },
  {
    "Menu": "Patient",
    "ParentMenuId": 3,
    "htmlId": "patient",
    "Id": 5,
    "Code": null,
    "IsActive": true,
    "EnteredBy": 0,
    "EnteredDate": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedDate": null
  }
]
```

Here is the issue:

[image]

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is some other problem in your code because your `MenuService` instance should be generated once in lifecycle only, if it get generated again then you would probably get null from it first of all edit `constructor(private _menuService: MenuService)` although this is not exact problem but you can dig via `console.log` in constructor of menuservice that it is singleton